# What does an empty list of "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" mean?

Tags: iis7

In IIS 7 for a certain subfolder of a web application.
Does an empty list imply a "deny all" or an "allow all"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what settings are being used. On other versions of IIS, there's an option called "Edit Feature Settings", which allows you to switch between "Allow All" or "Deny All".

[image: Screenshot]